# Mac App Store App and identifierForVendor

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

To uniquely identify an App in iOS 6 and above you use this code:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor
```

Is there an equivalent for Mac OSX?

Comment: Are you meaning the hardware uuid or an advertising id?

Comment: Well well, Mr I'L'I again. I have another Midi App :), this time for Mac OSX. My customer whats to protect his IP while at the same time not making things harder than necessary for his users. Having something like the iOS "identifierForVendor" would allow us to track usage across machines of the App and OK this without interfering with the users workflow! It's likely as his users are music producer types. An Advertising ID might be an idea, but we aren't actually advertising anything. I have investigated Mac Hardware UUID, Serial number and MAC addr, but all have the per machine limitation.

Comment: With a Vendor Id we can create a hash of vendor ID, Product and license and allow the users to use the IP we are trying project on any machine they want while at the same time putting a barrier to casual misuse of the IP, which is an XML file in this case alas.

Comment: To my knowledge OS X doesn't have an advertising id/vendor id, only iOS. So beyond getting the hardware uuid, the mac address, etc. you might need to come up with another creative way to do what you're wanting.

Comment: That's what my research has come up with alas. The worse bit is Apple seems to letting the Mac App Store shrivel on the vine. If you want to add this as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're trying to manage sales of an app outside of the app store - the store itself manages the same user installing apps they've already purchased on different machines. If this is true, you're not being reasonable expecting access to appstore-level methods outside of the store itself.

Comment: If your app is sold through the app store and you're just trying to track a single user for purposes of your own, then you could store a UUID in iCloud via NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.

Comment: @Richard Me too at the time, customer is always right! You are mostly correct, he was trying to protect his IP. App got done worked nicely ... but he's and back and this time into the App store it goes, huzzay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MAC doesn't have anything equivalent to iOS's identifierForVendor or advertising Id alas.

Answer (score 7):

For the record and users searching SO for this matter:
Apple documentation about validating a purchase receipt gives the implementation tip to get the GUID of a Mac, as the equivalent procedure for identifierForVendor:
[Get the GUID in macOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW14)

It is MAC address based, but is the choice of Apple for purchase hash control.