# Swift 3.1 Unique Mac Identifier

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, uniqueidentifier

Is there a way to get a unique device Identifier that would be maintained through App deletion/System reinstallation/User changes (different users would get same ID)? It seems that iOS has a bundleIdentifier, but I did not find anything similar for Cocoa.

Comment: Have you tried googling for the words "unique mac identifier"?  The first hit is an Apple technote that describes this exactly.

Comment: It's a 6 year old note, which further investigating seems to show is no longer supported by Apple and their AppStore.

Comment: IOKit is still supported by Apple, and neither of the functions there is deprecated (as of 10.12).  If they don't allow this on the App Store, it must be because they don't want to allow developers to get a unique device ID.

Comment: Since this question clarified/changed to be about the App Store, this looks like a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209097/mac-app-store-app-and-identifierforvendor/36485845

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mac App Store App and identifierForVendor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209097/mac-app-store-app-and-identifierforvendor)

Comment: mac has Hardware UUID just don't know how to get it using Swift

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/31838645/1187415 ?

Comment: IOKit  seems no longer work from some feedback of my clients.

Comment: @MartinR MAC address is no longer a valid unique id.

Comment: @zwcloud: Are you talking about macOS or iOS?

Comment: @MartinR I don't know the situation of iOS. But this question is about macOS, apparently. So I mean macOS.

Comment: @zwcloud: I just wanted to make sure :) – https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn1103/_index.html still mentions the MAC address as one option to identify a computer, is that not valid anymore?

Comment: @MartinR MAC address can be somehow edited by the user. And the doc is already 6 years old and should be outdated.